# Debian 8 boots into software rendering display just after I install it

Tags: drivers, debian, video, desktop

Well, this is a pain in the ass. Just after installing debian 8 on my machine and booting it for the first time, I'm greeted with a message telling me that debian 8 is running in software rendering display mode and that a video driver is either missing or is not working.  Running debian 8 on an HP 19 all-in-one desktop.

Comment: If you install the vanilla Debian and not the non-free firmware version ( http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/current/amd64/iso-cd/ ), then you have to manually install the non-free video drivers via apt. This is normal.

Comment: OK. Then what do I want for this particular machine?

Comment: `apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree` for ati cards. There are some nvidia related packages. I don't know which video card you have, but you can use google: "<my video card> debian linux"

Comment: Well, this repository I've hooked up to (gtisc.gatech.edu) doesn't have firmware-linux-nonfree for some odd reason. Can y'all point me to a nicer repository?